# Re-install Python on macOS

Tags: macos, install, python, data-recovery

I uninstalled Python on my Mac by moving all python-related files in my Mac (including system files) to the trash and emptying the trash. Now, I can't get Python 3 to work at all (despite reinstalling it). How can I get all of the deleted Python files back?

Update: I deleted the following files:

```
/Applications/Python
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework
/usr/local/bin/py
```

thon

Comment: If you had not put anything on the drive after you emptied the trash then *maybe.* I'd bet at least some of what you trashed has been overwritten and gone forever.

Comment: have you tried installing python using Anaconda?

Comment: Which python did you remove, the standard one installed as part of macOS, or a version you installed yourself?

Comment: The answer deals with apples  python but note that this is python 2.7. If you want python3 that is a different question.

Comment: If it's an OS with SIP enabled, then I don't think you can delete the System python.

Answer (score 7):

Ideally you can restore whatever you‘ve deleted from a backup.

If you removed the standard Python installation of macOS, [boot into the Recovery Partition](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314) (if any) and reinstall macOS from there. This should leave your other files intact, it‘s not a bad idea to do a backup before nevertheless.

Alternatively, you can through Homebrew.

Once Homebrew is installed, run:

```
brew install python@2
```

That won't likely install the same 2.7 revision you were using.

If you need an exact match, or don't/can't use Homebrew; I'd build it from source (if so, comment for further instruction).

<sub>Python 2 is end of life by January 1st 2020. Please don’t use it unless you are sure you are using an OS default.</sub>

---

<sub>If I am not in mistake, as of June 2020 macOS `10.15.4` (i.e., not fully up to date) is still at Python 2.7 (`2.7.16`).</sub>

<sub>If you are at `10.15.5` or later you are welcome to comment your mileage.</sub>

Comment: Which specific Mac model do you have if you assume it doesn‘t have a recovery partition?

Comment: +1 for the first part but -1 for the second. You have no choice but to reinstall the Apple supplied python as parts of the OS depend on it e.g. /usr/bin/xattr (and Homebre python is not the best install of python)

Comment: I agree with @Mark, may third-party software relies on specific python on specific macOS versions.

Comment: @nohillside depending on an installation process (e.g. corporative installation) there could be no recovery partition.

Comment: @EirNym I was not commenting on third party software but on actual parts of macOS - I would be very surprised if any third party software used Apple's python

Comment: @EirNym In such a corporate environment the typical user also won't be able to delete the standard python installation (or, if they are able to, can just have the machine set up again by corporate IT)

Answer (score 2):

```
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies python3
```

Then:

```
brew install python3
```

and done:

```
python3
```

Answer (score 1):

While restoring from a backup is always the best answer for recovering deleted files:

The files you list are not MacOS-bundled python components.

You should be able to download and run the Mac installer package from python.org directly:

https://www.python.org/downloads/

That should install everything necessary to use python3.